# zen report-dividing two summation values

Tags: xml, intersystems-cache, intersystems-cache-studio, intersystems-cache-zen

I want to divide two columns summations and make sure that the other number is not zero.

I tried with the statement below but it does not work

<element field"b1 div b2"  excelname="b3" isExcelNumber="true" excelNumberFormat="0" />

can anyone tell how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is part of the ReportDefinition but it seems not completely formatted properly.  I would expect to see something like

note the field="bi div b2" whereas you example is missing the = symbol.

and I would also think you would want to name the element so I would think it should include

name="*myFieldName*"

At the same time, I don't quite understand what you are wanting to accomplish.
Are you encountering an error?